Problem with changing colour of meshes, I've submited the proof for more help
I can't change the colour of anything, I am learning how to use Btions about changing the base colour of my monkey and its hat the colour stayed the same (red) no matter what I changed it to.
I don't know what the problem is, I am using Blender 4.2.1 LTS. If there's anything I am doing wrong or a bug.


This is my graphics card? Is this the problem?


Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

File displays fine on my computer, though all material previews show up as red like you viewport. This indicates it may be an issue with your computer rather than blender. What are your computer specs? What GPU do you have? Try updating your graphics card drivers, otherwise your card may not be supported

I added the picture of my graphics card, I don't know lot about computers and I don't understand graphics card details and stuff, please tell me if this is the problem and how can I solve it.

Your graphics card seems to be a low end model, which may be incapable of dealing with modern Blender. Try updating your drivers here https://www.amd.com/en/support/downloads/drivers.html/graphics/radeon-600-500-400/radeon-500-series/radeon-530.html If that doesn't help, try using an older version of Blender, like 4.1 which has a simpler viewport engine
